# Color of scope button text in UISearchBar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar which has to have a gray tint.

The problem I am having now is, that as soon as I set *any* tint color, the scope buttons get the same font color which results in a very poor contrast, if the buttons aren't selected.

If no tint is set, then the color vary depending on the selected state. Is there a way to achieve this, using a tint color?

#### The default

[image: with tint]

#### Using a tint

[image: no tint]

#### Update

Using `po [mySearchBar recursiveDescription]` I figured out that the `UISearchbar` has the following view hierarchy:

```
<UISegmentedControl>
    <_UISegmentedControlBackgroundView>
        <UIImageView>
    <UISegment>
        <UISegmentLabel>
        <UIImageView>
    <UISegment>
        <UISegmentLabel>
        <UIImageView>
    <UISegment>
        <UISegmentLabel>
        <UIImageView>
<UISearchBarBackground>
```

Comment: Do you mean the cancel button color?

Comment: @AppleDelegate The cancel button is not the problem in my case, since there the contrast is fine. I want to change the color of the scope buttons (Animals, Plants, Other)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I seem to recall running into similar issues when using tint colours. It appears that an unfortunate side effect is that it defaults colour related properties of the UIKit elements it affects.

I don't know whether there is a way to prevent this defect when using tints (I don't think there is), but the following workaround may be useful to you:

### iOS 6 and below

```
[searchBar setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[searchBar setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor greenColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

### iOS 7+

```
[searchBar setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[searchBar setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor greenColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

(Credit: @willyang)

Using the `UISearchBar`'s `setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:forState:` method you can configure the attributes of the scope bar button titles, including the text colour.

Comment: very elegant solution. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Because **UITextAttributeTextColor** is deprecated in IOS 7, should use **NSForegroundColorAttributeName** instead:

```
[searchBar setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor redColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[searchBar setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor greenColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

ref: http://www.downstairz.net/2013/11/24/uitextattributetextcolor-is-deprecated-in-ios-7/

Comment: This is the same as the answer to this question

Comment: @Besi same as which answer? This answer is a update not just a copy.

Comment: @Besi yes, I know. but it is different. This answer will adapt to iOS 7, since UITextAttributeTextColor is deprecated in iOS7.

Comment: Ok, I missed that little detail. Can you edit your answer otherwise I can't remove my down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

If you are building the SearchBar programmatically you can use the following to set the TextAttributes of the ScopeBar:

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil) // inside the class
```

....

```
// Background color
        searchController.searchBar.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSBackgroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow ], for: UIControlState.normal)
```

You can take a look at the UISearchBar methods (scroll halfway down to find the ScopeBar methods) to customize:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbar?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question correctly then this is what you are trying to do

```
for (id subview in yourSearchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews )
{

    if([subview isMemberOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]])
    {

        UISegmentedControl *scopeBar=(UISegmentedControl *) subview;
        [scopeBar setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
        [scopeBar setTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];//you can also set RGB color here 
        //scopeBar.tintColor =  [UIColor blackColor];         
    }

}
```